# How do you manage repositories for production/deployment of Node-React app?

Tags: node.js, reactjs, amazon-web-services, docker, continuous-deployment

Not long ago , we used to have server render pages and then React came for client side rendering and single page application.It introduced virtual DOM's and changed the way we write our code.

We require all these react libraries and install them as dependencies before writing our codes. Now we can break into many components , have many css and scss files including images. But at the end we will build the files, make compact bundle and serve from build folder.

Express get route

```
app.get('*', (req,res) =>{
    res.sendFile(path.join(__dirname+'/client/build/index.html'));
});
```

Heres, What I have understood :

Build folder is the place where webpack combines all the files and create minified bundle ready for deployment. That file is basically simple HTML and JS files which every browser can understand. As all the browser doesn't understand ES6 and much more, we have to convert all these files into plain language that every browser can understand.

Also, webpack-dev server is only for development purposes and we won't be running it into production.

1. Is virtual DOM/Real DOM just for development purposes? or
   are those react libraries also trans-piled while building the minified files? If later is the case , react is run on background mode on client's browser? I want to know how react takes care of client side routing after the building the app.
2. How do you manage github repositories for Node-React app? Do you keep two different repositories one for front end and other for back-end? Whats the industry standard?
3. **If you keep two repository, how do you deploy the front-end code? As you can't run the webpack-dev-server into production. Nor you can specify the public static (build folder) in your back-end(express server) as they are separated in two repos. How does, either the integration of these two repositories take place( lets say we have two AWS EC2 instance, one for each) or front-end get served from the front-end repo??). Can you actually use something like npm serve in production ??**

what am I trying to do ?

I want to deploy my node-react app on AWS. I have only one repository on github. I have one folder "client" inside my repo where all the react code sits with its package.json file. All the other files for server are inside root folder (server doesn't have its own folder and files are scattered inside root folder). So there are two package.json files, one inside root folder for server and one inside client folder.I am planning to run my-node app on a docker container.

Please help me understand the core concepts and standard practices for code hosting and deployment keeping large scale enterprise application in picture.

Comment: You are trying to mix up concept "Virtual DOM" and regular JS files trans-pilled into ES5 compatible code. Both are two different things. VDOM is a concept coined by React whose code is within ReactJS library

Comment: "I know what real dom and virtual dom is and how they work" - are you sure? It sounds like you think the virtual dom is for development only?

Comment: ;) What I meant is I know basics but whats the point , we are transpiling the code and we are not shipping babel and webpack , those are dev dependencies. once the build is completed it shouldn't have any connection with webpack?? or it should?? so what's behind the scene who goes ahead and look for any changes in virtual dom, and updates the real dom ?? @Rikin

Comment: Like @Rikin said, the virtual dom is managed by react. It doesn't have anything to do with webpack or babel. You are correct, you use webpack and babel *before* your code is executed to transpile and bundle it. After the code is transpiled and bundled, they are no longer used. But they never have an impact on the VDOM.

Comment: so you mean react libraries are also transpiled so it does run behind the scene which does scan the Dom and updates when its necessary??

Comment: Well think about how things are required in your react app. You import `react` in your components, that means you require some javascript from the react package in order for your code to work. You never import webpack or babel, they are tools used outside of your code that manipulate the code itself. So when you bundle the project, `react` code is included in that bundle too along with any other library you used.

Comment: React along with React DOM library (transpiled or not) are required and shipped to client in order to run your code on client browser.

Answer (score 3):

I would not go into explaining all the points in your question here because, @Arnav Yagnik and @PrivateOmega have both done a brilliant job at explaining most of them. I would definitely recommend you to read their answers properly and read the links provided for more information *before reading this answer*.

I would like to address your question of deploying a Node-React application. In production, generally, we have different deployments (or "repositories" as you mention in your question) for both the front-end (React) and back-end (Node). This allows your back-end to sit in an EC2 instance, for example, with auto-scaling to make sure that it can cope up with all the requests coming in.

As mentioned in the previous answers, and in your question as well, webpack compiles and minifies the React files into simple HTML and JS files, which most browsers can run (I'm not going to explain VirtualDOM here because it has already been perfectly explained in other answers). You would then take these minified files and serve them from an S3 bucket for example, because again, it is a single page application (also discussed in the other answers) and the business logic is already in the minified JS files and its just simply sending all requests to your back-end server.

Now for front-end, you can use TravisCI for example to **deploy** the **build** folder (the one you talk about in your question) to an EC2 instance and serve your files using NGINX or if you can configure a CDN deployment properly, you can serve the files from an S3 bucket for the most optimal performance.

You can think of *serving* the React application like sending a cryptic block of code to your user's browser. Now you can *deploy* this cryptic block of code to a publicly available S3 bucket, and serve it from there. Again, because of webpack and minification/uglification, no on would be able to make any proper sense of what your original code was, remember that you can still access all the code in Chrome's Sources tabs for example.

Comment: Can I deploy through CDN while still managing the user session (Cookies or JWT token)?

Comment: Absolutely, Cookies and JWT tokens and other details are stored in the browser. In your application you would instruct it to store these details in the browser. Infact, you can check this on Chrome yourself, just Inspect and go to *Application* tab, and you would find that Stackoverflow stores quite a lot of information in Local, Session Storage and Cookies. Go play with it. :) Every browser has something called Session Storage and Local Storage, and you can implement this in React as well read here for more information: https://www.robinwieruch.de/local-storage-react

Answer (score 1):

I would like to address this with different approach.

Server Rendered Pages : The concept has not changed, server when encountered with a DOC request it has to respond with a html. Now HTML may or may not contain scripts(can be either inline or a external server address). In case of question's context you can still ship HTML where it will download scripts that you have written(may include react or not). for most cases you can ship empty html with scripts tags which will download the scripts over network and execute them which would contain all the rendering logic.

To Answer your questions : 
1st : There is no background mode in a single threaded JS(unless we want to talk about workers but we can leave them out for this discussion). By writing in code you are not interacting with any DOM. You are instructing your components(extended by React) when to change their state and when to re-render(setState). React internally calculates the virtual DOM and compare to Real DOM to calculate actual changes that are to be made on Real DOM(this is very abstract answer, to get more understanding please read react docs, Baseline here is you are not interacting with any DOM just instructing React core library when to update and what is the updated state)

2nd : If you want to support SSR(server rendered pages). I would suggest to make 2 folders , **client**(this would include all client components and logic) and **server**(would include all server side logic) with different **package.json**  as packages differ for both applications.There is no such industry standard here, what floats your boat should work but generally making directories based on logical entities should satisfy separation and maintainability, if in future you think you want to fork out server and client in separate repos , it would definitely make the process easy.

3rd : You shun running webpack-dev-server in production. Files are generally not obfuscated hence payload is heavy(not to forget your written code is out there). Even if you want to make different repos, server can spit out html and html can request scripts with your client server.

How to deploy : Deploy your code and run :

> node server/app.js

and in app.js you can write the location block what you have mentioned.

P.S. : If you just need a server with that location block. do you really need a express server? You can upload the client build to a CDN and route your domain to serve index.html from the CDN(s3 bucket can also be used here)

Comment: Thank you for your response and time. This still doesn't clear the confusion I am having right now!

Answer (score 1):

I would like to start off with clearing up the terminologies as much as I can.

Like you said [server rendered pages](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Server-side_scripting) was a more prominent standard in the past, but it hasn't changed at all with the introduction of React, because even React has the support for [Server rendering or SSR](https://reactjs.org/docs/react-dom-server.html), which means HTML pages are generated at server side and then served to clients using browser.

And [client side rendering](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dynamic_web_page#Client-side_scripting) means, a HTML page is loaded to browser and then javascript code renders things on top of those HTML pages and make them interactive.

And [single page application](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Single-page_application) concept is that we have only a single HTML file or base HTML page on top of which based on user interactions and data from server it is rewritten continuously.

[Virtual Dom](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/React_(web_framework)#Virtual_DOM) is an amazing concept introduced by React. React library code recreates the structure of all elements(called DOM elements) of a HTML page in the memory in a tree form. This enables React algorithm called [Fiber](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/React_Fiber) to reconcile appropriate changes as per route update or any other changes first on this tree like structure before translating them onto the real elements in the HTML page.

[Babel](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Babel_(transcompiler)) is a transpiler to transpile latest features that browser engines haven't started supporting to code that they can understand, usually ES6+ code into pre-ES6 because all browser supports that. In React application, if you have written application using JSX syntax, babel supports transforming JSX into normal javascript also.

Yes, breaking up of pages into many components is possible due to compositional nature of components by React which means we can build complex things by combining small and more focussed things.

At the end before serving it to end users, we can't have web application lag due to the huge size of code, so during the build process, things like minifying(removing whitespace etc) and other optimization like combining multiple javascript files into one etc are done, and then compact bundle is served from build folder like you said.

Yes, build folder is where webpack does the minifcation and combination to create a bundle as small as possible. It is basic HTML and JS files that is understood by every browser, and if the code contains something that a particular browser doesn't support, appropriate support code or something called polyfill is also bundled with it. Technically you can't say browsers only understand pre-ES6 code because a lot of browser engines have implemented plenty of ES6 features already.

Webpack dev server is just used to serve a webpack application over a port like a node.js server and gives us features like live-reloading which is needed when you constantly make changes to your application codebase and it isn't needed at production because like we said previously, at production time it's just HTML and JS and nobody ever makes any changes on these files.

1. Virtual DOM is a memory representation or concept used by React Code just like we have stacks and queues and it not just used at development time. Yes and No. Because I think appropriate parts of react source code which is required to run the application would also be bundled before generating the production bundle.
2. I would say, don't have a preset way of things, because it is totally upto the developer and the team, because I have seen people using 2 seperate repos because frontend people work on frontend things whereas backend people work on backend things. But there's also a case when everyone's a fullstack developer and you can Technically have it in a single repo with a single package.json and use the backend to serve the frontend files and you have to manually install each react dependency and cannot directly use CRA or create-react-app like generator.
3. What has 2 repositories to do with front-end deployment in production? You don't need to run webpack-dev-server to server files in production. You can create a production bundle and then setup any http server to serve the generated bundle.

Regarding your current scenario I would say instead of having 2 package.json, you can go with a single package.json and install all dependencies together or go with a monorepo approach using something like [lerna](https://lerna.js.org/) or [yarn workspaces](https://classic.yarnpkg.com/en/docs/workspaces/).

But for a total beginner I would suggest 2 separate repositories to encounter less problems.

And a bonus point if you are not aware, you can write React in pre-ES6 code and also without JSX as well.

Comment: If you are keeping your files in two repos and you are not using express or any http server to serve your build files ,then, how would you serve your front end code? Just curious. If they are in two repo how does the integration takes place? what I have understood is we need to specify the static folder in express server, which is going to be build folder. But as they are separated in two repos and running in two docker container or two ec2 instances how can I integrate them ?

Comment: Well you need some sort of http serve  to serve your build files. It doesn't really have to be an express server, you can even use packages like serve for that purpose. So as far as integration goes, the frontend and backend are connected by REST APIs or any other technology like graphql and there isn't going to be a issue connecting it. So specifying static folder and serving it via express is just one of the ways to host the build react app. Over 2 docker containers, its just that the corresponding ports should be exposed and the containers have to be in same network.

Comment: If its two EC2 instances, probably CORS should be enabled and you can connect from frontend to backend using private IP. I hope the answer and both these comments help clarify your doubts to some extent.

Answer (score 1):

1) virtual DOM is basically to say that you are calling a function of react not the actual function which does manipulation on the real DOM

like this one

`document.getElementById("demo").innerHTML ="Helloworld"`

modifies the actual dom

but this

```
ReactDOM.render(
  <HelloMessage name="Taylor" />,
  document.getElementById('demo')
);
```

if you see this properly you aren't doing anything directly on the dom you are just giving the react function control to do things , internally react take cares of modifying the that dom element demo whenever the react wants to re-render it based on its own logic which is what they claim as optimized which is why people use it in first place. Yes when you build your code with webpack it does include react in it which is part of that minified code, so if you see any of the error stacktrace  in development you do see react is the starting point for it

2) I think its a choice to be made, as there are not restrictions on this

3) Coming to deployment , In general if you want use nodejs you might choose expressjs server type of deployment but otherwise generally its better to use a high performance server like Nginx or Apache or else if you just don't want to get into this whole drama of things people generally use heroku based deployment or else people are using special platforms like netlify,surge.sh these days (its super easy to deploy on these platforms).

Answer (score 1):

I believe others have done a pretty good job explaining the React Virtual DOM. In a simple and practical way, I’ll attempt to explain how I (would) manage the deployment of a dynamic website (including medium-sized enterprise systems) using NodeJS and React. I’ll also attempt not to bore you.

Imagine for once that React never existed and that you were building a traditional Server-Side Rendered application. Each time the user hits a route,  the controller works with the model to perform some business logic and returns a view. In NodeJS, this view is usually compiled using a template engine such as handlebars. If you reflect for a second, it becomes obvious that the view could be any html content which is then sent back to the browser as a response.

This is a typical response that could be sent back:

```
<html>

<head>
    <title>Our Website</title>
    <style></style>
    <script src="/link/to/any/JS/script"></script>
</head>

<body>
    <h1>Hello World </h1>
</body>

</html>
```

If this response hits the browser, obviously “Hello World” is displayed on the screen.
Now, with this simple approach, we can do powerful things!

**OPTION 1:**
We can designate one controller to handle all incoming routes `app.get("*", controllerFunc)` and render one view for our entire server.

**OPTION 2:**
We could ask multiple controllers to handle different routes and render route-specific views from our server.

**OPTION 3:**
We could ask multiple controllers to handle different routes and generate pages on-the-fly (i.e. dynamically) from our server.

If we were building a traditional web application, option 3 would be the only reasonable standard. Here, pages are generated dynamically for different routes. However, with option 1, we can produce a quality Single-Page Application where the response sent to the server is an empty html page but with the built JS script that has the ability to manipulate the DOM – Yes, **React**! Here’s what such a response might look like:

```
<html>

<head>
    <title>Our Website</title>
    <style></style>
    <script src="/link/to/any/JS/script"></script>
</head>

<body>
    <h1>Hello World </h1>
    <div id="root"> </div>
    <script async type=”text/javascript” src="/link/to/our/transpiled/ReactSPA.js"></script>
    <!--async attribute is important to ensure that the script has access to the DOM whenever it loads. This also makes the script non-blocking -->
</body>

</html>
```

Clearly, we’re giving all the responsibility to the generated SPA and all routing logic is handled on the client-side (See, [react-router-dom](https://reacttraining.com/react-router/web/guides/philosophy)). On the server side, we can introduce the concept in option 2 and tweak NodeJS route handlers to listen to another specific route for any REST API communication. If you’re familiar with NodeJS, the order in which routes are registered either by `app.get()` or `app.post()` matters.

However, using option 1, we can quickly become limited and only able to serve one Single-Page application from that server. Why? Because we have asked one controller to handle all non-API incoming routes and render one view. We also risk serving an unnecessarily bloated JS file. Users are served the complete website when all they probably wanted was just the landing page.

If we look to the option 2 though, we can tweak things a lot more and serve multiple Single-Page Applications for different routes, all from our server. This approach helps to reduce the sizes of the JS build being sent to the browser. A typical example would be a website that has a welcome page (or an introduction directory), a login page and a dashboard.

By assigning controllers for different routes, we can build SPAs uniquely for those routes. SPA for the intro page, another for the login page, and then another for the dashboard. Yes, the browser would have to load while transitioning between the three, but at least we highly increase initial render time for our website. We can also use the more secure option of cookie for authorization rather than the less secure option of storing session tokens on `localStorage`.

In a more advanced setting, we could have dynamic websites with different React components rendered as widgets within the dynamically generated page. Actually, this is what Facebook does.

The way to build such SPAs or components is pretty simple. Start up a react project and configure webpack to render the production-ready JS file into your preferred public static directory within the server-side repo. The `<script>` specified in the view can then easily load these built react components since they exist within the scope of the server-side’s public directory.

In essence, this means one repo with several client directories and one server directory where the destination of the production build files to be generated by webpack for each client project is set to the server’s public static directory. So, each client side’s directory is a project (either full SPA or simple React Component as a widget) with it’s own webpack.config and package.json file. In fact you can have two separate config files – production and development. Then, to build, you use `npm ~relevant command~` for either production or development build.

You could then go ahead to host it the way you would host any NodeJS application. Because, the main application is the NodeJS - that's where the server is. Replace NodeJS with PHP and Apache/NGINX, the concept still remains the same.

Comment: Thank you for your time and response.